# How can I run a Simio model from a C# application using the API

Tags: c#, api, simulation

I would like to run a Simio model from a C# application. I do not want to open Simio and run the models from there. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can run experiments with the following code:

```
// Open project
string[] warnings;
ISimioProject project = SimioProjectFactory.LoadProject(getFile.FileName, out warnings);    
IModel model = project.Models[1];
```

And then you have access to the experiments of the model. You can add new experiments, or run an existing one:

```
IExperiment experiment = model.Experiments.Create("MyExperiment");

// Setup the experiment (optional)
// Specify run times.
IRunSetup setup = experiment.RunSetup;
setup.StartingTime = new DateTime(2010, 10, 01);
setup.WarmupPeriod = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
setup.EndingTime = experiment.RunSetup.StartingTime + TimeSpan.FromDays(runtime);
experiment.ConfidenceLevel = ExperimentConfidenceLevelType.Point90;
experiment.LowerPercentile = 5;
experiment.UpperPercentile = 95;

// Add event handler for events from experiment
experiment.ScenarioEnded += new EventHandler<ScenarioEndedEventArgs>(experiment_ScenarioEnded);
experiment.RunCompleted += new EventHandler<RunCompletedEventArgs>(experiment_RunCompleted);
experiment.RunProgressChanged += new EventHandler<RunProgressChangedEventArgs>(experiment_RunProgressChanged);
experiment.ReplicationEnded += new EventHandler<ReplicationEndedEventArgs>(experiment_ReplicationEnded);

// Run Experiment, will call event handler methods when finished etc.
experiment.RunAsync();
```

Hope this helps you get started. Feel free to ask anything more.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Have a look at the SimioProjectFactory class. From there you can load existing .spfx files and run attached experiments. You can also see the results and so on.

Here is how to load a project and obtain the first model in it. From there, all is similar as with writing an add-in:

```
string[] warnings;
ISimioProject project = SimioProjectFactory.LoadProject("Test.spfx", out warnings);    
IModel model= project.Models[1];
...
```

Have fun!
Nicolas

Comment: What is the context of these functions? How would I go about actually running the experiment? I cannot find anything referencing SimioProjectFactory in the API.  Would it be possible to see a simple script that runs one of the example simio models as if you opened up the program and hit run? Thanks so much!

Comment: The SimioProjectFactory is in the SimioAPI namespace and is included in the SimioDLL. You can find more information on the Simio API forum, such as here: http://www.simio.com/forums/search.php?keywords=stop+model+from+API&t=836&sf=msgonly